# Pre-paid 3G/4G SIM with Tor

Tags: tor, parrot-os

I was wondering if I would have an extra layer of anonymity by using a mobile wireless device with a pre-paid SIM (paid in cash) alongside Anonsurf and Tor browser? Or would it just be more hassle without extra benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does add some extra level of anonymity in case your real (non-Tor) IP address is exposed to an attacker comparing to if you were using your home IP address. But whether or not it would be significant depends on many things, as it still could be traced to specific hardware and location. So if you're a journalist investigating government corruption, this may add a bit of hassle for them. But if you're only worried about not seeing targeted ads, it is definitely overkill.